# monero-stratum private pool error

Tags: mining-pools

I'm trying to run monero-stratum from https://github.com/sammy007/monero-stratum but monero-wallet-cli don't connect (in the same host):Use "help" command to see the list of available commands.

---

Error: wallet failed to connect to daemon: http://localhost:1111. Daemon either is not started or wrong port was passed. Please make sure daemon is running or restart the wallet with the correct daemon address.

The pool logs this error:
Malformed request from 127.0.0.1: invalid character 'G' looking for beginning of value.

My host is Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. Wihtout monero-stratum monerod and monero-wallet cli in natural port 18081 works and are mining.
So I suppose a bug in monero-stratum.

Comment: I reckon you're just pointing something to the wrong port. Double check your config.

Comment: Thank for your help, but I don't think so: I've tried all 3 ports configured in config.json: 1111, 3333 and 5555, also with 127.0.0.1 and the real IP. I'm suspecting some go libs and json parser: o installed by deb package: go version go1.6.2 linux/amd64. I've also look in monero-stratum src and this error string does not figure in. But this string exists in the binary (found with strings): strings -d ./build/bin/monero-stratum|grep 'looking for beginning of value' looking for beginning of value
looking for beginning of value

Answer (score 2):

You don’t connect monero-wallet-cli to monero-stratum, but general pool mining software such as XMR-Stak and XMRig. You specify the wallet address to receive your solo mining block reward in monero-stratum’s config file. You need to run monerod as well, and let monero-stratum connect to it.

Comment: Hi, I'll try one of this miners, thank you. I thought monero-wallet could connect to stratum just changing the daemon port. And yes monerod is running and it. Now I can start minining on the monerod daemon whith the monero-stratul-cli command, but maybe it cannot connect to stratum (it was not clear on monero-stratum docs. Thanks again

Comment: There's no such thing as monero-stratul-cli. Stratum connects to the daemon in order to fetch block templates which define jobs assigned to each connected miner. Check out the web interface of monero-stratum which displays connection status for both the daemon and miners.

Comment: Wow, yes I'm wrong: monero-wallet-cli and monero-wallet-rpc. And yes also, monero-stratum web (port 8082)shows connection on monerod on usualy port 18081. Are you really using monero-stratum (go version)? But sorry for my errors. My problem is really with this answer: **Malformed request from 127.0.0.1: invalid character 'G' looking for beginning of value** from monero-stratum.

Comment: I confirmed that you get that error when you try to connect monero-wallet-cli to stratum by `monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address 127.0.0.1:1111`. You seem to be totally confused. An example of correct usage would be: `xmrig -o 127.0.0.1:1111`.

Comment: OK, thank you, it seems I'm really confused, but I'll try this.

Comment: It seems also,not so clear docs on github site: XMRig is a high performance Monero (XMR) CPU miner, with official support for Windows. It works on linux too?

Comment: Of course, most miners work on Linux. You just need to compile it yourself. Read their documentation.